# Using Charles breaks my android studio builds, but only on day 2

Tags: android-studio, vpn, charles-proxy

So this is an odd one.  I installed charles and get all the certificate installed on my mac and my android emulator.  I have to do this so that I can use some test servers that are only available over our work VPN, and for some reason the emulators can't use the test servers over the VPN unless they are set up to use charles.

So I get charles set up and everything works for the rest of the day.  However the next morning when I go to build the code I get the following build error:
`build failed Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Then if I invalidate caches and restart android studio then build I get a different error:
`Unable to resolve dependency for ':feature_referral@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava-27.0.1-jre.jar (com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre)`

The dependency changes each day So I don't think it is this specific dependency.  The only way I've been able to fix this is to uninstall Android Studio and reinstall it.

Could any one explain what exactly is going on under the hood?  I can't find any explanations online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that in Charles under Proxy -> SSL Proxying Settings -> SSLProxying I had added *. (wild card)

Once I removed the wild card entry I was able to build again from Android Studio.